# Dynamically redirect all requests with the same url path to the same upstream server

Tags: http, redirect, nginx, load-balancing

I'm trying to create a basic nginx LB that redirects requests to the same upstream server if the url path repeats itself without relying on the senders cookies/ip.

for example lets say I have an LB called **A.com** and a target called **A.com/target**.
The first time a request is sent to **A.com/target** the LB would redirect to a random server in the upstream, so far so good, the problem is that on the second request with the same url path (Doesn't matter who makes that request, therefor cookies are out of the question) I need the LB to redirect to the same server it redirected to last time.

I just cant get it to work properly so I wanted to ask if anybody has a proper way to do it with nginx or with any other simple LB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can balance by URL with the help of nginx upstream hash feature introduced in version 1.7.2 
Official docs are here [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#hash).

```
upstream backend {
    hash $scheme://$host$request_uri; # put any variables here

    server backend1.example.com;
    server backend2.example.com;
    server backend3.example.com;
}
```

Comment: Can I do it on specific parts in the uri for example run it against a regex Capture group?

Comment: Sure. Replace the $scheme://$host$request_uri with $myvar and define a location that includes myvar as named capture. location ~ ^/(?<myvar>.*)$ for example.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider adding "consistent" parameter at the end of the hash row in order to avoid massive rehashing in case of an upstream server changes- addition or removal. Haproxy is also an option with it's "hash-type consistent" parameter group for the backend section.